# How do I work with (minimize/resize/un-float) a captive portal?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

Captive portals are those screen that float over everything while you're being logged into some network with terms of service (like a coffee shop or airport).

The one I encounter regularly takes almost a minute to connect after I "agree."

These "captive-portals" feel like they were built for a dystopian future...

How can I make these windows minimizable or move them out of my field of vision so I can use my screen for other things while I await a viable network connection?

Comment: Put that in an answer! With a screen shot

Answer (score -1):

Because of System Integrity Protection (SIP), a feature introduced in El Capitan to protect system files from modification by malware, you can’t just move the file if you have that feature enabled (it’s on by default).

So, first, you have to disable SIP on this case

**Follow these steps to disable SIP:**

1. Restart your Mac.
2. Before OS X starts up, hold down <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
3. From the **Utilities** menu, select **Terminal**.
4. At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: `csrutil disable`
5. The terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
6. From the Apple menu, select Restart.

After this,

1. In the **Finder**, select **Go** > **Go to Folder**.
2. Enter `/System/Library/CoreServices` and hit return.
3. Find `Captive Network Assistant` (or `Captive Network Assistant.app`), click it, and rename it with an extra word, like **Captive Network Assistant Do Not Launch** and press return.
4. Enter your password when prompted to make the change.

After this again, enable SIP, following the first process shared on this comment just by typing `csrutil enable`

Comment: Will this disable that window entirely, or make it minimizable/resizable/not float?

Comment: Unfortunately these instructions will disable it completely, so I don’t think it answers the question. @Seph

Comment: If the portal is set up correctly, navigating to captive.apple.com afterwords should take you to the login page in your browser